# Convert an int array to a single int

Tags: c++

I'm trying  to convert array[]={1,2,3} into  a int number=123;  how can I do that ?

my code is this:

```
int main()
{

    int array[]={1,2,3};
    int number;

    for (int i =0; 3<i ; i++){
        int val=1;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++ ){
                val*=10;
        }
        number += array[i] *val;

    }
    cout<<number;

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's it doing wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't take two `for` loops to do this, especially when the first one has a typo that prevents it from working: `3<i`.

Comment: You gave the expected result which is already pretty good, but it's usually a good practice to tell people in the question what are the actual results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding numbers in the wrong "direction". To keep the digits in order, you need to multiply your `number` variable by 10 and then add `array[i]` instead of multiplying `array[i]` and adding it to `number`.

You also need to initialize `number` to zero before you use it, because a variable has a random value until it's explicitly given one.

You also need to do `i < 3` ("loop while `i` is less than three") instead of `3 < i` ("loop while 3 is less than `i`", which is never true).

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};
int number = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    number *= 10;
    number += array[i];
}

cout << number;
```

Let's walk through what happens.

- In the beginning, `number` is equal to zero.
- We get to the loop. First, `i` equals 0.

  - We multiply `number` by 10. For the first iteration, `number` is still zero after that.
  - We add `array[0]` (1) to `number`. `Number` is now 1.
- `i` now increments and is equal to 1. 1 is less than 3, so we go in the loop body again.

  - We multiply `number` again by 10 to make room for the next digit. `number` is now equal to 10.
  - We add `array[1]` (2) to `number`. `Number` is now 12.
- `i` increments and is equal to 2. 2 is less than 3, so we repeat.

  - We multiply `number` by 10, again to make room for the next digit. It's now 120.
  - We add `array[2]` (3) to `number`, making it 123, the desired result.
- `i` increments and becomes 3. 3 is obviously not less than 3, so we exit the loop.
- We print `number` (123) to the console.

Comment: can you explain what is the meaning of number*= 10;  "*" is  a pointer right ? and why the value 10?

Comment: @user3123562 No, it's not a pointer. `number *= 10;` is equal to `number = number * 10;`

Comment: Yes, `a *= b` is a shorthand for `a = a * b`, the same as `a += b` is a shorthand for `a = a + b`. `*` is *also* used in different contexts for pointers, but that's not the case here.

Comment: oh  my mistake I was thinking probably is number =number*10, but because i don't see it so often maybe is a pointer.  but why 10 ??

Comment: @user3123562 Because you have to multiply the number by 10 to get the correct number (it's very simple math). Take a paper and write down each step one by one and see what happens. By multiplying first time, you get 0 because its initial value is 0, because the first element is only one digit, so the after execution of the first loop, number will be 1. When you get the second one, which is 2, you multiply 1 by 10 and add the 2 to it so you get 12, then for 3, you multiply 12 by 10 and get 120 and add the 3 on it and you get 123.

Comment: I just added an English description of what happens to my answer, but it's basically what @user2699298 just said. When you multiply `number` by 10, you make room for the next digit.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using streams, as your case is really about lexical interpretation.

```
int number;
std::array<int, 3> arr { 1,2,3 };
std::stringstream ss;
for(int i : arr) ss << i;
ss >> number;
std::cout << number;
```

or course if you don't need the number itself you can just use `std::cout`.

```
std::array<int, 3> arr { 1,2,3 };
for(int i : arr) std::cout << i;
```

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure it's the best approach for someone who's clearly very new to programming.

Comment: @user1618143 why? How is using raw constructs (like int[]) better than using highlevel abstractions?

Comment: For real-world use, it clearly isn't. But this doesn't appear to be a real-world problem, just a student trying to figure out some basic stuff. `std::array` could reasonably be used in this context, but not streams.

Comment: Because they are simpler. You don't need to `#include` anything, you don't need to care about whether or not you are in C++11 mode, you don't need to care about the initialization syntax, you don't need to know about templates.

Comment: @user1618143 that's your opinion. The OP can make their own mind up.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int numarray[] = {1,2,3};
    int num = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i>=0; i--)
    {
        num += numarray[2-i]*pow(10,i);
    }

    std::cout << num;
    return 0;
}
```

Replace 2 with the maximum size (m) of a number array minus 1 for different sized arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your first `for` loop is messed up. Try this:

```
for (int i =0; i<3 ; i++){
    int val=1;
    for(int j=0; j<(3-i); j++ ){
            val*=10;
    }
    number += array[i] *val;

}
```